# Default Qt console application doesn't cout "Hello World"... or do anything else

Tags: c++, qt

Strange problem this:

I wrote an OpenGL app which compiled in QT but then opened a terminal which sat there doing nothing. As a test I created a new project... the default plain C++ project. It is supposed to:

```
int main(){
  cout << "Hello World" << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

But the terminal opens and nothing ever happens. Tried a google search, but didn't find anything. Does anyone know what the problem might be?

Comment: I tried placing a breakpoint after int main. Debugging never gets to the breakpoint - or ignores it?

Comment: Are you including iostream and using namespace std?

Comment: Do you have `CONFIG += console` in your project file?

Comment: Application output would suggest that the program is running infinity and never exits correctly. Closing the terminal makes the terminal disappear, but killing the application with the button inside QT makes it disappear and reports that it exited with code 0.

Comment: @Derek - Yes that is there, Template = app, and config -= qt

Answer (score 1):

I have had the same problem. Open "Projects" tab and in "Build & Run" -> "Run" try take off flag from "Run in terminal" then put it back. It looks strange but helped me.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
#include <QtCore/QCoreApplication>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    std::cout << "hello world" << std::endl;
    return a.exec();
}
```

From Qt's documentation: 
`The QCoreApplication class provides an event loop for console Qt applications.
This class is used by non-GUI applications to provide their event loop. For non-GUI application that uses Qt, there should be exactly one QCoreApplication object. For GUI applications, see QApplication.`

Comment: QtCore/QCoreApplication - No such file or directory? Do I need to edit the .pro file @Derek ?

Comment: Probably. Try changing your project file to the following: `QT       += core,
QT       -= gui,
TARGET = ConsoleTest,
CONFIG   += console,
CONFIG   -= app_bundle,
TEMPLATE = app,
SOURCES += main.cpp
`
No commas and change main.cpp to your file name.

Comment: Okay done, but still lingering terminal which doesn't do anything?

Comment: It looks like you can actually get away with not having the QCoreApplication (for now). 

Are you using QtCreator?

Answer (score 0):

use

```
std::cerr<<
```

it works for me